# can get value of hashMap with [] in jsf?

Tags: jsf

in my jsf file i hava:

```
<f:facet > #{main.res['CORE_COMMON_LABEL_ACTIONS'] </f:facet>
```

and in back Bean i hava

```
 public Map<String, String> getRes() {
        return resourceBean.getResourcesMap(currentLocale);
    }
```

that main.res['CORE_COMMON_LABLE_ACTION'] refer to getRes() and invok it.

WHAT is the []?can get value of hashMap with [] insteadof get()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes. you can get Map value with []. try something like this:

```
private Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public void add(String key, Object value) {
    objects.put(key, value);

}

public Map<String, Object> getObjectsMap() {
    return objects;
}
```

for example we have an entry :

```
 add("hi" , "test");
```

then you can get value like this:

```
#{yourBean.objectsMap['hi']}
```

It will work;